# android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

```
mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
            return arg0 == arg1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return views.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager)container).removeView(views.get(position));
        }


        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
            ((ViewPager)container).addView(views.get(position));
            return views.get(position);
        }
    };

        mTabPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
```

> After My Fragment has created,  I call function:

```
public void AddView(View v, int index)
{
    views.add(index, v);
    mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

> But it report android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$LayoutParams cannot be cast to 
>   android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams

Answer (score 1):

```
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager)container).removeView(views.get(position));
    }


    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
        ((ViewPager)container).addView(views.get(position));
        return views.get(position);
    }
```

try this, use your ViewPager instance to replace the cast scope " ((ViewPager)container)", like this, mViewPager.removeView(views.get(position));

Comment: thank you for answering.   It still report the same error using your method.

Comment: can you setLayout for your  ViewPager ? make sure your LayoutParams is ViewPager.LayoutParams。